# get the position of end effector

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am just started doing research of Baxter Research Robot with ROS Indigo.
Anybody know how to get the position of end effector on say the right arm of the robot in MoveIt! or Gazebo?
I am currently just simulating the robot in software environment.

Thanks,
Andy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233466/get-the-position-of-end-effector/) by [andydar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26755/andydar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-05-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If all you want is the current pose, you can skip MoveIt altogether and get the info directly from TF. The transformation you're looking for is probably `base -> right_gripper`. Check out the [TF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/) to see how to get transforms between links.

You only need to use MoveIt for this if you want to get transformations for robot states that are *not* the current robot state, e.g. to answer the question "what would the transform between `base` and `right_gripper` be if I executed plan X generated by MoveIt".

Of course you can do it with MoveIt too if you want, something like this:

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group;
// ...
robot_state::RobotStatePtr state = group.getCurrentState();
Eigen::Affine3d &transform = state->getFrameTransform("right_gripper");
```

See the [MoveGroup](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html) and [RobotState](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_core/html/classmoveit_1_1core_1_1RobotState.html#details) documentation.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-10-08**:
+1 for showing simpler usecase. Just curious, why not mention [MoveGroup::getCurrentPose](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroup.html#af3680fb747b0d570dac822893cef695f) for MoveIt! example?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-10-10**:
Good point @130s, that's easier than my Moveit example.